# What the best way to keep track of a javascript object reference when prototyping

Tags: javascript, object, reference

what's best practice when it comes to keeping track of an object reference in javascript:

```
function class1(param) {
this.param = param;
self = this;
}

class1.prototype.method1 = function () {
console.log(self.param);
}

$('document').ready(function () {
   object1 = new class1('foo');
   object2 = new class1('bar');
   object1.method1(); // expected: foo , actual: bar 
   })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d7q5f/

Currently self appears to be global and is overridden in the constructor of object2. I'd be very grateful if someone could offer some advice.

Comment: You probably only need a reference to `this` when you're going to pass a function member as a callback or event handler. In that case it's better to pass a bound function or a closure as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 under `the this variable` Then use `var self = this` and make sure it's in the same scope as self is now within constructor scope so anything outside the constructor can't access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep track, just use `this` like so:

```
function class1(param) {
this.param = param;
}

class1.prototype.method1 = function () {
console.log(this.param);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function class1(param) {
    this.param = param;
}

class1.prototype.method1 = function () {
    console.log(this.param);
}

$('document').ready(function () {
   var object1 = new class1('foo');
   var object2 = new class1('bar');
   object1.method1(); // expected: foo , actual: foo 
});
```

Why you want to add this `self` thing?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Lyx/)